# Extracting information from anchor elements leading to pdf files

Tags: python, html, scrapy

I am using **Scrapy** to crawl and scrape data from websites, which mainly consists of html pages and pdf files (I have modified `IGNORED_EXTENSIONS` to allow scraping pdfs).

I need to extract text which is trapped between `<a>` tags:

```
<a href='some_document.pdf'>I need this text</a>
```

Obviously, I can't do response.text or response.css, since there are only bytes to be read (you get an AttributeError).

One thing that came to my mind was crawling the page, extracting all links from that page and saving them in the text file. It worked, except that I ended up with a lot of duplicate links, links that was broken (think 403, 404, 500) or a lot of links I didn't care about. I think there must be a better way!

While reading Scrapy documentation I stumbled upon the doc for [LxmlLinkExtractor](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/link-extractors.html#module-scrapy.linkextractors.lxmlhtml). There in the *"constructor"*, it has 2 *interesting* fields:

- tags (str or list) – a tag or a list of tags to consider when extracting links. Defaults to ('a', 'area').
- attrs (list) – an attribute or list of attributes which should be considered when looking for links to extract (only for those tags specified in the tags parameter). Defaults to ('href',)

And this got me thinking whether it is possible to grab values of an attributes of an `<a>` element before crawling it. Am I correct? And if yes, how can I grab text between  tags?

Source code:

```
class ArchiveSpider(CrawlSpider):

...some code...

rules = [
        Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=[re.compile('pdf', re.IGNORECASE)]), 
                           callback='parse_pdf', 
                           follow=True),
        Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)
    ]

    def parse_pdf(self, response):
        yield dict(url=response.url)

    def parse_item(self, response):
        if re.search(re.compile('pdf', re.IGNORECASE, response.headers.get('Content-Type').decode('utf-8')):
            parse_pdf(self, response)
        title = response.css('title::text').extract()[0].strip() if response.css('title::text') else ''
        yield dict(title=title, url=response.url)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand you correctly, but couldn't you do something like this:

```
text = response.xpath('//a/text()').extract()
```

You'll have to specify the desired `<a>`-elements in the xpath, the `text()` selects the text between the tags.